# Power BI data sources fail to refresh because of privacy levels

Tags: powerbi

I keep getting an error when I try to refresh the dataset in the online Power BI services.

```
Data source error: Information is needed in order to combine data. Please specify a 
privacy level for each data source.;Information about a data source is required.. 
The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface. Table: <table_nmame>.
```

I have tried to set different **privacy levels** in the Power BI desktop report, from 'organizational' to 'public'. Unfortunately, nothing works. The desktop version refreshed with seconds, the online refresh takes minutes to fail.

Under Files > Options and settings > Data source settings > Edit Permissions... I set and changed them. The SQL server is up and running.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you go to https://app.powerbi.com and have a look at the published dataset's settings/permissions there.

I have experienced a similar case earlier where I had to set the permissions for a data source in the published dataset settings.

Comment: I couldn't find a permission setting page that would enable me to change privacy levels on the dataset?

Answer (score 1):

codeape was quite right. I just wanted to post the right screenshot for everyone to easier find the mentioned settings:

[image: online Data source settings]

I used the "Microsoft account"-login locally and apparently it didn't translate well into the cloud service.

[image: PowerBI Microsoft login local]

It had to be redone like in the screenshot above and then everything worked out fine.
Thanks!